# antd preload raw default layout when lagging

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, ant-design-pro

Help me fix this bug! I'm using Ant Design, I've installed the language, but when the page loads, it renders Raw characters once. After refreshing, it displays the normal language again.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4ibc.png)

If used InPrivate window to login, it will be Chinese at pagination, refresh website will not see that.
Can i use useRef()